# Libevent bufferevent's evbuffer_add

Tags: c++, sockets, buffer, libevent

I am using Libevent library 2.0 for socket communication.
In order to add data to evbuffer, I am using evbuffer_add. The bufferevent stores the data in its internal buffer and transfers the data via socket using some predefined timeout and watermark settings.

My question is, is there any way to control the data transfer? Can we transfer the data explicitly any time and after any random number of bytes being written?

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind this function is fire-and-forget. However, you can add a callback so that when the send finally happens, you can do some things:
 evbuffer_add_cb

This doesn't allow you much control, but you can use it for some behaviors like appending the buffer.

Comment: I would like to transfer fix number of bytes each time. However, even after setting write watermark high = 4K, sometimes only less than 1K bytes are being sent. Is there any way to force transfer by adding some padding bytes or any other mechanism?